# how to fix SurfaceView and android camera size

Tags: java, android, camera, surface

I write program, camera for android. I use next code

```
package camera;



public class SurfaceCamera extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    TextView testView;

    Camera camera;
    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

    PictureCallback rawCallback;
    ShutterCallback shutterCallback;
    PictureCallback jpegCallback;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.video_surf);

        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();

        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                try {
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/Octopus/gif/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
                    outStream.write(data);
                    outStream.close();
                    Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Picture Saved", 2000).show();
                refreshCamera();
            }
        };
    }

    public void captureImage(View v) throws IOException {
        //take the picture
        camera.takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);
    }

    public void refreshCamera() {
        if (surfaceHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            camera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here
        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
        // the preview.

        refreshCamera();
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            // open the camera
            camera = Camera.open();

        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            // check for exceptions
            System.err.println(e);
            return;
        }
        Camera.Parameters param;
        param = camera.getParameters();
        //param.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_NEGATIVE);
        // modify parameter
        param.setPreviewSize(600, 900);
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        camera.setParameters(param);
        try {
            // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw
            // the preview.
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // check for exceptions
            System.err.println(e);
            return;
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // stop preview and release camera
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }

}
```

layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.javacodegeeks.androidsurfaceviewexample.AndroidSurfaceviewExample" >

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/capture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="captureImage"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Capture"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Where I see on surface image (on surface) the picture is distorted, stretched at the corners https://www.dropbox.com/s/ul5enua7tb07zkr/shot_000002.png?dl=0

but if I capture photo all ok https://www.dropbox.com/s/zibn89tl38a8eur/1424809721079.jpg?dl=0

Please help, what I write wrong? How I can fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: That's because you preview size that is assigned to the camera does not fit the view that you are assigning to it.  The easiest solution is to get the preview size from the camera that best fits that view and then resize the view to match the dimensions / aspect ratio of the preview size.

Comment: resize surface width and height ?

Comment: The `SurfaceView` width and height yes.  If you do this with a gravity of center in the current window you are working with you will have a view gaps on the sides, but this would be a quick and easy solution to get an aspect fit.  The picture as you pointed out is a different size defined when you setup your camera.  So, it will remain unaffected and can be completely different than your preview size you assign.  Well at least in the older camera code.  Not quite up to pace on the latest Camera2 API.